# Two 3D matrix of different sizes but similar composition, compare the likelihood that a given item is present in a column

Tags: matrix-calculus

### Overview

Given that 3D Matrix 1 and Matrix 2 have the same number of items "P" randomly dispersed, how can it be shown that the liability of "P" in any given column <A, B, C, D> is less when using a Matrix B that has 9 additional rows?  By liability, stating fewer "P" items are impacted/lost if a given column < A, B, C, D> is removed.

#### Context

Matrix 1 has six(6) rows and Matrix 2 has fifteen (15) rows. Matrix 1 and Matrix 2, both have four columns and each column has a z-axis with "n" items (for simplicity start with 3, but the final number 128)

| matrix | Row Count | Columns | z-axis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Matrix 1 | 6 | 4 | 3 |
| Matrix 2 | 15 | 4 | 3 |

### Attempt with Python

My inaugural approach with python was to generate each matrix and inserting placeholders P / e(empty). However I realize that won't prove, though it may show/imply that same number of "P" in Matrix B is less liable.

Comment: If the $\sf P's$ are distributed evenly, then if you lose **one of the four** columns, you've lost **a quarter** of the $\sf P's$ in either case.

Comment: And if they are not distributed evenly but randomly?